# How troubleshoot Synapse Spark Notebook that runs manually, but times out if run from a Pipeline

Tags: apache-spark-sql, azure-synapse, azure-synapse-analytics

- Spark Notebook, if run manually from the notebook (whether under my
  credentials or running  Managed Identity) runs successfully in about
  3 minutes
- If placed in a Pipeline - prior to Tuesday, it ran fine.
- Since Tuesday, it fails when in a Pipeline.
- It's using the same Spark Pool as when manually run successfully.
- There were no updates to the notebook's code prior to the sudden failure
- The committed version of the notebook is the same as the one that runs fine successfully.

It seems to time out after 2 hours on the last step (INSERT).

Error Message:

```
{
"errorCode": "6002",
"message": "Error: Job aborted.\norg.apache.spark.sql.errors.QueryExecutionErrors$.jobAbortedError(QueryExecutionErrors.scala:651)\norg.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:284)\norg.apache.spark.sql.delta.files.TransactionalWrite.$anonfun$writeFiles$1(TransactionalWrite.scala:456)\norg.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$6(SQLExecution.scala:111)\norg.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:183)\norg.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:97)\norg.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:779)\norg.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:66)\norg.apache.spark.sql.delta.files.TransactionalWrite.writeFiles(TransactionalWrite.scala:391)\norg.apache.spark.sql.delta.files.TransactionalWrite.writeFiles$(TransactionalWrite.scala:355)\norg.apache.spark.sql.delta.OptimisticTransaction.writeFiles(OptimisticTransaction.scala:103)\norg.apache.spark.sql.delta.files.TransactionalWrite.writeFiles(TransactionalWrite.scala:221)\norg.apache.spark.sql.delta.files.TransactionalWrite.writeFiles$(TransactionalWrite.scala:218)\norg.apache.spark.sql.delta.OptimisticTransaction.writeFiles(OptimisticTransaction.scala:103)\norg.apache.spark.sql.delta.commands.WriteIntoDelta.write(WriteIntoDelta.scala:337)\norg.apache.spark.sql.delta.commands.WriteIntoDelta.$anonfun$run$1(WriteIntoDelta.scala:98)\norg.apache.spark.sql.delta.commands.WriteIntoDelta.$anonfun$run$1$adapted(WriteIntoDelta.scala:91)\norg.apache.spark.sql.delta.DeltaLog.withNewTransaction(DeltaLog.scala:252)\norg.apache.spark.sql.delta.commands.WriteIntoDelta.run(WriteIntoDelta.scala:91)\norg.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.WriteIntoDeltaBuilder$$anon$1$$anon$2.insert(DeltaTableV2.scala:279)\norg.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.SupportsV1Write.writeWithV1(V1FallbackWriters.scala:79)\norg.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.SupportsV1Write.writeWithV1$(V1FallbackWriters.scala:78)\norg.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.AppendDataExecV1.writeWithV1(V1FallbackWriters.scala:34)\norg.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.V1FallbackWriters.run(V1FallbackWriters.scala:66)\norg.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.V1FallbackWriters.run$(V1FallbackWriters.scala:65)\norg.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.AppendDataExecV1.run(V1FallbackWriters.scala:34)\norg.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.V2CommandExec.result$lzycompute(V2CommandExec.scala:43)\norg.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.V2CommandExec.result(V2CommandExec.scala:43)\norg.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.V2CommandExec.executeCollect(V2CommandExec.scala:49)\norg.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.$anonfun$applyOrElse$1(QueryExecution.scala:113)\norg.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$6(SQLExecution.scala:111)\norg.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:183)\norg.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:97)\norg.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:779)\norg.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:66)\norg.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.applyOrElse(QueryExecution.scala:113)\norg.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.applyOrElse(QueryExecution.scala:106)\norg.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDownWithPruning$1(TreeNode.scala:584)\norg.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:176)\norg.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDownWithPruning(TreeNode.scala:584)\norg.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$logical$AnalysisHelper$$super$transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:31)\norg.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning(AnalysisHelper.scala:267)\norg.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning$(AnalysisHelper.scala:263)\norg.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:31)\norg.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:31)\norg.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:560)\norg.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.eagerlyExecuteCommands(QueryExecution.scala:106)\norg.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.commandExecuted$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:90)\norg.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.commandExecuted(QueryExecution.scala:84)\norg.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.<init>(Dataset.scala:231)\norg.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.$anonfun$ofRows$2(Dataset.scala:101)\norg.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:779)\norg.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.ofRows(Dataset.scala:98)\norg.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.$anonfun$sql$1(SparkSession.scala:622)\norg.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:779)\norg.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sql(SparkSession.scala:617)\norg.apache.livy.repl.SQLInterpreter.execute(SQLInterpreter.scala:129)\norg.apache.livy.repl.Session.$anonfun$executeCode$1(Session.scala:716)\nscala.Option.map(Option.scala:230)\norg.apache.livy.repl.Session.executeCode(Session.scala:713)\norg.apache.livy.repl.Session.$anonfun$execute$4(Session.scala:492)\norg.apache.livy.repl.Session.withRealtimeOutputSupport(Session.scala:936)\norg.apache.livy.repl.Session.$anonfun$execute$1(Session.scala:492)\nscala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)\nscala.concurrent.Future$.$anonfun$apply$1(Future.scala:659)\nscala.util.Success.$anonfun$map$1(Try.scala:255)\nscala.util.Success.map(Try.scala:213)\nscala.concurrent.Future.$anonfun$map$1(Future.scala:292)\nscala.concurrent.impl.Promise.liftedTree1$1(Promise.scala:33)\nscala.concurrent.impl.Promise.$anonfun$transform$1(Promise.scala:33)\nscala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:64)\njava.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)\njava.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)\njava.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)",
"failureType": "UserError",
"target": "Rebuild_factGL",
"details": []
```

I've tried:

1. Assigning the pipeline a larger Spark Pool
2. Placing the notebook in a brand new pipeline by itself
3. Recreating the notebook, and running that from a pipeline

How can I troubleshoot better?

Comment: Can you provide Notebook activity configurations? Also, check whether it results same when running any other sample Notebook from the pipeline with same spark pool.

Comment: @RakeshGovindula sorry, what is 'Notebook activity configuration'? And no, other notebooks run fine in a pipeline, just this one does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved-ish.

**TLDR:** Use PARSER_VERSION = '2.0' when doing OPENROWSET on CSV files.

Approximately one week after the Spark Notebook stopped working when run in a Pipeline, it also stopped working when ran manually.  I'm not sure why the delayed reaction there, but now it was being consistent.

I isolated it back to a SQL Serverless View the Spark Notebook was calling.

That view had suddenly gone from running in 1.5 minutes, to timing out.

In particluar, the View would time out if 3 conditions were met - calling both numeric columns, and including a where clause on date. If 2 conditions were met - it ran in 1.5 minutes. All 3 = a time out.

This was reproducable behavior for 3 weeks.

I never was able to troubleshoot what exactly was occuring. But, all the underlying tables of the View, ultimately, were coming from CSV viles in the datalake. I changed all of those to PARSER_VERSION = '2.0', and now it runs, and faster than it did prior to the hiccup.

Comment: Glad you were able to solve it :), sometimes there is erratic behaviour in these PaaS applications because they are constantly being worked on for new features, and sometimes they break things when they introduce new stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem with my managed identity notebook. When I was running it manually in the notebook, it worked fine. However, in the pipeline, it was failing due to direct storage access using direct link The issue was resolved by using the following approach for reading or writing data:

If you need to read or write data, consider using the following approach:

from notebookutils import mssparkutils

```css
mssparkutils.fs.mount(
    'abfss://containerName@storageName.dfs.core.windows.net',
    '/mountpoint',
    {'linkedService':'linkedServiceName'}
)
```

After mounting the storage, you can use the mounted path for reading and writing data:

```css
jobId = mssparkutils.env.getJobId()
path = 'synfs:/' + jobId + '/mountpoint/*.parquet'
```

Please ensure that your Blob storage has the necessary permissions to interact with Synapse.

Comment: Thanks - all the other pipelines work though.  I think it may have been a delayed effec t- a few days later, the spark notebook wouldn't run manually either.  I'll put the solution in my answer.